# Not able to display values in another viewcontroller from TableView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to display the details of one one table row onto another viewController. But it shows an error saying ' fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value'

The code for my VC is as follows:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDataSource,   UICollectionViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var nameForUser: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var loginButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!


let allEvents = Events.allEvents
var nextScreenRow: Events!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //nameForUser.text! = "Please Enter Name Here"
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    textField.text = ""
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.allEvents.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("eventsCell")!
    let event = self.allEvents[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = event.eventName
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: event.imageName)
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = event.entryType
    //cell.textLabel?.text = allEvents[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    nextScreenRow = allEvents[indexPath.row]

    performSegueWithIdentifier("tryToConnect", sender:self)

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.allEvents.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let sec = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("eventsSec", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GridCollectionViewCell

    let event = self.allEvents[indexPath.row]


     sec.imageView.image = UIImage(named: event.imageName)

     sec.caption.text = event.entryType

    return sec
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("tryToConnect2", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "successfulLogin"){
        segue.destinationViewController as! TabController
        //let userName = nameForUser.text
        //controller.userName = userName

    }

    else if (segue.identifier == "tryToConnect"){
            let dest = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailedEventViewController
            dest.deatiledEvent.text = nextScreenRow.eventName
            dest.eventType.text = nextScreenRow.entryType
            dest.imageView.image = UIImage(named: nextScreenRow.imageName)
            }


}



@IBAction func loginButtonWhenPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    let userName = nameForUser.text

    if userName == "" {
        let nextController = UIAlertController()
        nextController.title = "Error!"
        nextController.message = "Please enter a name"

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "okay", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
            action in self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }

        nextController.addAction(okAction)
        self.presentViewController(nextController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}  

}
```

When I run this, it shows the error. I have also assigned the delegates for the table view. The code for 'DetailedEventVC' is:

```
import UIKit

class DetailedEventViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var deatiledEvent: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var eventType: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

Why does it show that the values are nil?
Help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
The 'EventsDetails.swift' file which has the details of events are a structure. Is there anything wrong in the way I'm calling the values?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

struct Events {
let eventName: String
let entryType: String
let imageName: String

static let EventKey = "NameKey"
static let EntryTypeKey = "EntryType"
static let ImageNameKey = "ImageNameKey"

init(dictionary:[String : String]) {
    self.eventName = dictionary[Events.EventKey]!
    self.entryType = dictionary[Events.EntryTypeKey]!
    self.imageName = dictionary[Events.ImageNameKey]!
}
}

extension Events {

static var allEvents: [Events] {

    var eventsArray = [Events]()

    for d in Events.localEventsData(){
        eventsArray.append(Events(dictionary: d))
    }

    return eventsArray
}

static func localEventsData()-> [[String: String]] {

    return [

        [Events.EventKey:"Metallica Concert in Palace Grounds", Events.EntryTypeKey: "Paid Entry", Events.ImageNameKey:"Metallica"],
        [Events.EventKey:"Saree Exhibition in Malleswaram Grounds", Events.EntryTypeKey: "Free Entry", Events.ImageNameKey:"SareeExhibition"],
        [Events.EventKey:"Wine tasting event in Links Brewery", Events.EntryTypeKey: "Paid Entry", Events.ImageNameKey:"WineTasting"],
        [Events.EventKey:"Startups Meet in Kanteerava Stadium", Events.EntryTypeKey: "Paid Entry", Events.ImageNameKey:"StartupMeet"],
        [Events.EventKey:"Summer Noon Party in Kumara Park", Events.EntryTypeKey: "Paid Entry", Events.ImageNameKey:"SummerNoonParty"],
        [Events.EventKey:"Rock and Roll nights in Sarjapur Road", Events.EntryTypeKey: "Paid Entry", Events.ImageNameKey:"RockNRollNight"],
        [Events.EventKey:"Barbecue Fridays in Whitefield", Events.EntryTypeKey: "Paid Entry", Events.ImageNameKey:"BBQFriday"],
        [Events.EventKey:"Summer workshop in Indiranagar", Events.EntryTypeKey: "Free Entry", Events.ImageNameKey:"SummerWorkshop"],
        [Events.EventKey:"Impressions & Expressions in MG Road", Events.EntryTypeKey: "Free Entry", Events.ImageNameKey:"ImpressionAndExpression"],
        [Events.EventKey:"Italian carnival in Electronic City", Events.EntryTypeKey: "Free Entry", Events.ImageNameKey:"ItalianCarnival"]

    ]
}
}
```

Comment: Check whether your DetailedEventViewController outlets are connected with storyboard

Comment: try to create properties and pass data to them instead of passing data to your outlets. Because your outlets are not connected when you try to access them from your first viewController.

Answer (score 1):

Create properties in your destination viewController and use them like below

```
import UIKit

class DetailedEventViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var deatiledEvent: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var eventType: UILabel!
var myImage = UIImage?
var eventDetails = ""
var typeOfEvent = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
imageView.image = myImage
deatiledEvent.text = eventDetails
eventType.text = typeOfEvent
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

and then in your first viewController you can access them like

```
let dest = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailedEventViewController
        dest.eventDetails = nextScreenRow.eventName
        dest.typeOfEvent = nextScreenRow.entryType
        dest.myImage = UIImage(named: nextScreenRow.imageName)
```

Comment: make sure you have set the Delegate and DataSource and try to put break points to find exact line where error is occuring

Comment: Yes, I have set the delegates and data sources for the table view. Very unexpected to get this error. Is it because that 'nextScreenRow' actually is a datatype of 'Events', which I have defined it as a Structure with three entities?

Comment: Basically where Ever you are using "!" or "?" it means its an optional. And you need to provide it a value befre using it. When Compiler does not find a value for that optional it throws an error like yours.

Comment: Would it okay, if I showed you the 'events' structure also? I'll edit the question?